# ubuntu 14.04 pulseaudio automatically module loading

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

i would like pulseaudio to automatically load a module named `module-bluetooth-discover`, rather then executing `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` each time after the system boots.

i removed the condition surrounding the loading of the module in pulseaudio configuration, but the result is the same.

```
$ cat /etc/pulse/default.pa | grep -i module-bluetooth-discover -B1 -A1
#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
#.endif
```

i see no errors in `/var/log/syslog`. can one offer some assistance?

Comment: Are you using blueman?

Comment: @Jeremy31: i am.

Comment: There may be more than one `default.pa`.  Settings in `~/.pulse/default.pa` or `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` will override those in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` for a single user. See e.g. if you guest account sees your Bluetooth device to find out.

Comment: @Takkat: i have only `default.pa` file. any other idea?

Comment: Uninstall blueman and use Ubuntus bluetooth manager.  Blueman is removing module-bluetooth-discover when it loads

Comment: @Jeremy31: can you please convert your comment to an answer, so we could close this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uninstall Blueman and use Ubuntu's Bluetooth Manager you can avoid having to manually load `module-bluetooth-discover` every boot

This was supposed to have been fixed in 1.23-git201406261335-deb-1ubuntu1 and it seems to work on my laptop but it is possible it only works because I uninstalled the original version I had before installing this version

Comment: Jeremy, Could you have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/673156/atheros-ar9485-wifi-disconnects-randomly) too?  One of the mods needs help! **;-)** And then ping me in chat so I can remove this comment!  **<:-)**

Comment: What is Ubuntu's Bluetooth Manager? (I am using Xubuntu 14.04 with blueman.)

Comment: @jarno Ubuntu uses gnome bluetooth if I remember correctly.  I think Ubuntu may have removed the fixed Blueman version from the repos.  If you are using the AMD64 Xubuntu you can find the fixed blueman deb file [here](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/179296522/blueman_1.23-git201406261335-deb-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

Comment: I got the same from [ppa:cschramm/blueman](https://launchpad.net/~cschramm/+archive/ubuntu/blueman)