# Wireless problem in Hp ab-029TX with ubuntu 14.04 Realtek

Tags: 14.04, wireless, realtek

I bought a new Hp pavilion 15 ab-029TX. I installed ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows8. There is a problem with accessing wireless in ubuntu. It shows either out of range or doesn't connect to the internet. I'm new to linux. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: 08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Comment: How can I install it without internet since I don't have an internet connection? Is there any way that I can download in windows and install from ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can install this driver offline.

Download these files and copy them to your Home folder in Ubuntu:

[dkms](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb)

[rtlwifi-new-dkms](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.5~trusty_all.deb)

[linux-firmware](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/linux-firmware_1.144%2Bar3012_all.deb)

Then run in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: +1 Could you have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/673156/atheros-ar9485-wifi-disconnects-randomly) too? (That's one of the mods) and ping me in the chat, so I can remove this comment!  **;-)**

Comment: When I click on dkms link it is saying "Sorry, we can't find your kernels".

Comment: @user455102 The package has been upgraded. I fixed the link.

Comment: Even after restarting the problem exists. Still showing the network out of range. Installation was fine without errors.