# I can't connect my Ubuntu 16.10 to Wireless

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.10

I have two OS in my computer: Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.10 (I installed it today). I'm trying to connect to the wifi and it doesn't work. My Ubuntu is recognizing all the connections available, but my machine only connects through Ethernet. I'm beginner in Linux, but I did some tests. Apparently, I have a Wireless Driver.

```
cassia@Cassia-PC:~$ sudo iwconfig
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

cassia@Cassia-PC:~$ rfkill list all
0: samsung-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: samsung-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

cassia@Cassia-PC:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       descrição: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 01
       serial: 24:f5:aa:52:de:4a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.8.0-39-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.182.53 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:f0600000-f067ffff memory:f0680000-f068ffff

cassia@Cassia-PC:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [144d:4105]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Can anybody help me find a solution? I've tried so much things.

Comment: See if my answer @ http://askubuntu.com/q/673156/300665 helps at all.  I would check `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'` and see if your access point is using TKIP as that causes problems.  I have the same wireless chipset using 16.04 with no connection issues but I am not using TKIP

Comment: Jeremy31, apparently my problem was in my router configuration. I put my Mac Address in my Control Access of the Router.