# Dell inspiron WiFi disconnecting Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, atheros

I installed ubuntu 18.0.2 LTS on Dell inspiron [Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 ] and I am getting problem about the disconnection of WIFI (keep on connecting and disconnecting). But, this is happening only on my home WIFI. Even from mobile hotspot, it works perfectly.

I tried to solve this issue, by reading different post like mentioned below and could not succeed even after 10 days. 
[Atheros AR9485 wifi disconnects randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673156/atheros-ar9485-wifi-disconnects-randomly)

Also many post wrote about [Brodcom modem ] and wcl driver updates, which doesn't work in mine case.

finally, I thought of writing a question here. 
For the details about networks, I am adding details below asked in few old posts.

***Edit: required information. Following is the link for network details as mentioned in comments by Mchid.***

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JR4Z9DD7Ct/

I am looking for help, how I can solve this issue?

PS. I am not able to comment on other post/s to clear further doubt.

Comment: Please follow these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/167115 and please post a link to the information in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, here is a helpful tip: to easily format code in a post, you can paste the code and then highlight all of the code and then press CTRL+K to automatically format the highlighted code in your post. You can format multiple lines of code like this instead of using backticks.

Comment: Check results for `iwlist scan` I think your wifi is using TKIP encryption as my AR9485 wouldn't stay connected as long as TKIP was used on my router

Comment: Thanks, I posted the link with required information,

Comment: @mchid The AP they are trying to use does not show TKIP

Answer (score 0):

Because there are 8 people in your area using the same channel that you are using (Channel 1) but there are only two people using channel 6, you should get the best performance by switching to one of the following channels:

**Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz**

**channel 09: 2.452 GHz**

or

**Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz**

You can set the channel frequency in the settings of your wireless router.

Usually, this will fix the issue. Because this is only happening at home, I believe this is the core issue that you are dealing with. If you try this and you are still having the same trouble, there are a few more tricks we can try to solve the issue so please post a comment to let me know if this does not work for you. Thanks!

[image: frequency distribution]

[image source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)

---

`iwlist channels` shows:

```
wlp7s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
```

`iwlist scan` shows the channels in use in your local area:

```
Channel occupancy:

      8   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      3   APs on   Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      4   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

Comment: Thanks @mchid I will update later, don't have access for router setting.

Comment: on making the cloned mac address: "Stable" it is working fine, till now. i want to check it for one day. if problem comes again. I will update

Answer (score 0):

My laptop wifi is working fine after I made my mac address in wifi setting "Stable". Maybe it will helpful for someone else also.